# Intersections in polygons

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, polygons

I'm having troubles solving the following problem which is about combinatorics: 
let $n$ be a natural number $\ge 3$, and a convex polygon with $n$ vertices.

Each vertices are supposed to connect each other in straight lines, so that three lines never intersect at the same point.

The problem is about finding the number of intersections inside the polygon with respect to $n$, the number of vertices.

Here is an example with $n = 6$
[image: http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/37/Polygone-convexe.png]

Thanks a lot in advance !!

Comment: Have you tried drawing the diagram for a triangle, a quadrilateral, and a pentagon, counting the intersections, and seeing if you notice a pattern?

Comment: yes I did, but didn't see any :(

Comment: Maybe you could start by trying to find a formula for the number of lines that are intersecting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hint:* From a point of intersection, you find four of the $n$ vertices by following the two lines in both directions.